# Changing Sound Recognition Language

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I succeeded to at mic button on my search field but when i press on that button i want it to recognize voice as if it is  English Language rather than the phone owner's language.

Answer (score 0):

define de the language in your intent:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
```

More info : **[RecognizerIntent EXTRA_LANGUAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE)**

Comment: where should i add this? i have no intent for sound recognition, i just activated it in xml file :(

Comment: :D pof! yeah.. but should i create any on click listeners or define sth. to create an intent? brain is just confused a bit..